# how to use a watch method to permit or not a variable being set to true or false in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a logic issue.

I have a data variable which set true or false once a button is triggered in a html tag, showing  a vertical(true) or horizontal image(false)and viceverse on the click(@click).

Being more specific im setting the battleships game , and in the positioning of ships is where this problem surges.

At the bottom of the grids containers i could place my ship image in a horizontal mode cause is allowed, but should not  turn to vertical image  cause then its limits would encroach the grids container one.

So basically im wondering if is there a general idea about how could i ban this turning-to-vertical(false)data variable from its true condition cause of being in a specific position in that grid.

In plain words just wondering how could i say to that variablle in "true" to not change on click to "false" cause its position in fact doesn't allow it.
Thanks in advance!!!

````
<div>
<template>
    <div>
            <img
              v-if="shipOrientations['Carrier']"
              id="tester5"
              class="drag5"
              src="../assets/carrierHorizontalView.png"
              draggable="true"
              data-ship-length="5"
              data-ship-type="Carrier"
              @dragstart="dragStart"
              @dragover.stop
              @click="drawShip($event, 'Carrier'), orientationShips($event)"
            />
            <img
              v-else
              id="tester6"
              class="drag5v"
              src="../assets/carrierAboveView.png"
              draggable="true"
              data-ship-length="5"
              data-ship-type="Carrier"
              @dragstart="dragStart"
              @dragover.stop
              @click="drawShip($event, 'Carrier'), orientationShips($event)"
            />
          </div>
    <v-btn @click="putShips">Play</v-btn>
    <v-btn @click="putSalvos">FIRE!!!</v-btn>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions, mapMutations, mapState } from "vuex";
// import tester from "../components/tester";
export default {
  name: "GamesGrid",

  props: ["gamePlayerId", "id"],

  data() {
    return {
      positionShips: [],
      opponentShots: [],

      initialDropPosition: [], /////todas las variables del drop exteriorizadas
      ship_idEx: [],
      shipEx: [],
      positionIdOfImgEx: [],
      getNumOfPositionIdEx: [],
      getStringOfPositionIdEx: [],
      ShipColorsEx: [],
      currentShipPosition: [],
      targetEx: [],
      /////objetos del ship
      shipOrientations: {
        Destroyer: true,
        PatrolBoat: true,
        Submarine: true,
        BattleShip: true,
        Carrier: true
      },

      ///////

      shipsToSendBackEnd: [
        { typeShip: "Destroyer", shipPositions: [] },
        { typeShip: "Submarine", shipPositions: [] },
        { typeShip: "PatrolBoat", shipPositions: [] },
        { typeShip: "Carrier", shipPositions: [] },
        { typeShip: "BattleShip", shipPositions: [] }
      ],

      shootToPositions: [],

      ////////
      rows: ["", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
      columns: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]
    };
  },

methods: {
    ...mapActions(["fetchingGamePlayerId", "getPlacedShipsGamePlayer"]),
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    putShips() {
      return this.$store.dispatch("getPlacedShipsGamePlayer", {
        gamePlayerId: this.gamePlayerId,
        ships: this.shipsToSendBackEnd
      });
      console.log(this.shipsToSendBackEnd);
    },

    putSalvos() {
      return this.$store.dispatch("getPlacedShotsGamePlayer", {
        gamePlayerId: this.gamePlayerId,
        salvos: this.shootingstoPositions
      });
      console.log(this.salvosSack);
    },
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    dropShip(e) {
      const ship_id = e.dataTransfer.getData("ship_id");
      const ship = document.getElementById(ship_id);
      let target = e.target;
      let positionIdOfImg = target.id.match(/[a-z]+|[^a-z]+/gi); //getting all Id splited in letra y numero
      let getNumOfPositionId = Number(positionIdOfImg[1]); //numero dentro del array
      let getStringOfPositionId = positionIdOfImg[0]; //letra dentro el array

      // ////esto debe ser exportado a la data para despues renderizarlo a condicionales de posicion en
      let newShipLoc = [];
      this.targetEx = target;
      this.ship_idEx = ship_id;
      this.shipEx = ship;
      this.positionIdOfImgEx = positionIdOfImg,
      this.getNumOfPositionIdEx = getNumOfPositionId,
      this.getStringOfPositionIdEx = getStringOfPositionId,
        //////logs de todos los elementos
      console.log(ship_id);
      console.log(e.target);
      console.log(positionIdOfImg);
      console.log(getNumOfPositionId);
      console.log(getStringOfPositionId.charCodeAt(0));
      console.log(ship.dataset);

      this.conditionals(); ///importado como condicionales de orientation y demas
    },
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    conditionals() {

      if (
        (this.targetEx.id.length != 1 &&
          this.getNumOfPositionIdEx + Number(this.shipEx.dataset.shipLength) <
            12 &&
          this.shipOrientations[this.shipEx.dataset.shipType]) ||
        (this.targetEx.id.length != 1 &&
          this.getStringOfPositionIdEx.charCodeAt(0) +
            Number(this.shipEx.dataset.shipLength) <
            76 &&
          !this.shipOrientations[this.shipEx.dataset.shipType])
      ) {
        this.shipEx.style.position = "absolute";
        this.shipEx.style.display = "block";
        this.targetEx.appendChild(this.shipEx); ///adhiere la nave al place donde se posiciona la misma
        this.orientationShips();
      } else {
        console.log("sorry you cant place it");
      }
    },
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    dragStart(e) {
      const target = e.target;
      console.log(e.target);

      e.dataTransfer.setData("ship_id", target.id);

      // setTimeout(() => {
      //   target.style.display = "none";
      // }, 1);
    },
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    removeShips() {
      console.log("remove");

      var ship = this.shipEx;
      let ShipColors = Array.from(
        document.getElementsByClassName(ship.dataset.shipType)
      );
      console.log(ShipColors);

      for (let i = 0; i < ShipColors.length; i++) {
        ShipColors[i].classList.remove(ship.dataset.shipType);
      }
    },
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    orientationShips(event) {
      let newShipLoc = [];
      const ship = this.shipEx;

      this.removeShips();

      console.log(event);
      console.log(this.ship_idEx);
      console.log(this.currentShipPosition);
      console.log(this.positionIdOfImgEx);
      console.log(this.getNumOfPositionIdEx);
      console.log(this.shipEx.dataset);

      if (this.shipOrientations[ship.dataset.shipType]) {
        if (this.getNumOfPositionIdEx + Number(ship.dataset.shipLength) < 12) {
          console.log("Horizontal");
          for (let i = 0; i < ship.dataset.shipLength; i++) {
            //horizontall
            newShipLoc.push(
              this.getStringOfPositionIdEx + (this.getNumOfPositionIdEx + i)
            );
            document
              .getElementById(
                this.getStringOfPositionIdEx + (this.getNumOfPositionIdEx + i)
              )
              .classList.add(ship.dataset.shipType);
          }
          this.shipsToSendBackEnd.forEach(shipToSend => {
            if (shipToSend.typeShip == ship.dataset.shipType) {
              shipToSend.shipPositions = newShipLoc;
            }
          });
        } else {
          console.log("sorry you cant");
        }
      } else {
        if (
          this.getStringOfPositionIdEx.charCodeAt(0) +
            Number(ship.dataset.shipLength) <
          76
        ) {
          console.log("Vertical");
          for (let i = 0; i < ship.dataset.shipLength; i++) {
            //vertical

            newShipLoc.push(this.getStringOfPositionIdEx.charCodeAt(0) + i);

            document
              .getElementById(
                String.fromCharCode(
                  this.getStringOfPositionIdEx.charCodeAt(0) + i
                ) + this.getNumOfPositionIdEx
              )
              .classList.add(ship.dataset.shipType);
          }
          this.shipsToSendBackEnd.forEach(shipToSend => {
            if (shipToSend.typeShip == ship.dataset.shipType) {
              shipToSend.shipPositions = newShipLoc;
            }
          });
        }
      }
    },
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    drawShip(event, ship) {
      this.getNumOfPositionIdEx = Number(
        event.target.offsetParent.id.split("")[1]
      );
      this.getStringOfPositionIdEx = event.target.offsetParent.id.split("")[0];

      console.log(event);
      console.log(document.getElementById(event.target.id));

      console.log(event.target.id);
      this.positionIdOfImgEx = event.target.offsetParent.id.split("");
      console.log(this.positionIdOfImgEx);

      this.shipEx = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
      console.log(this.shipEx);

      this.shipOrientations[ship] = !this.shipOrientations[ship];
      // console.log("orientation");

      this.orientationShips(ship);
    },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getGamePlayerId", "getPlayerInfo"])
  },
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  created() {
    this.fetchingGamePlayerId(this.gamePlayerId);
    this.salvosToSend();
  },
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Destroyer
  // Submarine
  // PatrolBoat
  // Carrier
  //BattleShip
                    ```
````

Comment: https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/i/ifstatme.htm

Comment: Could you send a sample of you code ?